# MybatisPlus Of org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException

Tags: java

> Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='title', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=VARCHAR, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #2 with JdbcType VARCHAR . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).

### Bad code

```xml
WHEN title LIKE '%#{title}%'
```

### Good code

```xml
WHEN title LIKE CONCAT('%',#{title},'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the quotation marks turn the slot into a string, and mybatis did not recognize the slot.Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54577420/revisions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).